# Problem with using modules from a package or separate notebook

Tags: packages

I saved some modules into the same package or notebook which I call `ModuleLibrary.m`

I then get/call this package using `Get[DirectoryPath\\ModuleLibrary.m]` in my actual analysis notebook.

However when I come to use some module, it doesn't work. Mathematica behaves as though the called module is uninitialised E.g. If I go `MyModule[Data]` I just get the output `MyModule[{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3}...}]` rather than the actual result.

The modules themselves definitely work as I can use them inside the `ModuleLibrary.m` file itself, and they behave as expected.

The package itself is laid out as:

```
BeginPackage["MyPackageName`"]

Begin["`Private`"];
MyModule1[x,y]:=Module[Some code here...]
End[];

Begin["`Private`"];
MyModule2[x,y]:=Module[Some code here...]
End[];

Begin["`Private`"];
MyModule2[x,y]:=Module[Some code here...]
End[];

EndPackage[];
```

Comment: You need to export MyModuleN to MyPackageName contex. Put it after BeginPackage.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for answering, do you think you can show me what you mean?

Comment: @QuantumPenguin please read http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html

Comment: @RolfMertig I think I see, inside `BeginPackage[...]` I need to specify the module names I want to use outside of the package itself?

Comment: @QuantumPenguin yep, see linked topic, and topics linked there too.

Comment: @kuba can you show me what you mean I tried? I still can't get this to work...
``